# From the same website I can scrape a table with beautifulsoup from one page category but not the other although the html are the same

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I can easily **scrape** the table from this url:

```
url = "https://www4.yggtorrent.li/engine/search?name=&description=&file=&uploader=&category=2145&sub_category=all&do=search&page="
```

With the following code:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table'})
print(table)
```

But not from this one (*return None*) although it's from the same website, it's just another page category:
**!!! the link below will send you to a page with links to porn content but not diplaying it !!!**

```
url = "https://www4.yggtorrent.li/engine/search?name=&description=&file=&uploader=&category=2188&sub_category=all&do=search&page="
```

I've also tried the following variants:

```
r.text => r.content
html.parser => lxml, html5lib
```

I've compared the two html pages with: https://www.textcompare.org/html/
But couldn't find the difference which could make it return None.

Comment: How did you find `category=2188`  ?

Comment: Doing `soup.find("table",class_="table")` gives me the right result!

Comment: @Kshitiz I've just tried and it doesn't work for me :( What did make you want to try "class_" instead of "class"? Because in the html it's clearly written "class". Did you use "r.text" or "r.content" with "html.parser" or "lxml" or "html5lib"? Which browser are you using? Trying to understand why it's working for you and not for me!

Comment: @BhavyaParikh by selecting the "xxx" category on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Heres that complete code that, I had tried which worked for me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page=requests.get("https://www4.yggtorrent.li/engine/search?name=&description=&file=&uploader=&category=2145&sub_category=all&do=search&page")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"lxml")

print(soup.find("table",class_="table"))
```

This is giving me the exact result as you are trying to do.

Comment: You didn't read me well. It's the second link (url) provided which is problematic. The "category=2188" not the "category=2145"! This one: "https://www4.yggtorrent.li/engine/search?name=&description=&file=&uploader=&category=2188&sub_category=all&do=search&page="

Comment: Ain't you seeing this that is not giving any results, at all. Then will you do scraping with no results?

Comment: I don't understand French but while translating "Aucun résultat ! Essayez d'élargir votre recherche..." into English I am getting "No result ! Try to expand your search ..." and I think it is straightforward.